# How do I use a def function to create a random list without duplicates

Tags: python

I need to use a def function to create a random list of numbers without duplicates.

I have tried to use the two functions below but they both end up producing a single value

```
import random
def fill(nx, x, y):
    lx = []
    j = 0
    while (j < nx):
        r = random.randint(x, y)
        if r not in lx:
            lx.append(r)
            j = j + 1
            return lx


n = 25
a = 10
b = 50

myList = fill(n, a, b)
print(myList)
```

and

```
import random
def fill(nx, x, y):
    lx = []
    for j in range(nx):
        randNum = random.randint(x, y)
        if randNum not in lx:
            lx.append(randNum)
            return lx
n = 25
a = 10
b = 50

myList = fill(n, a, b)
print(myList)
```

They both only add one integer to the list and I cant figure out how to make it to add all 25 need in it. If I could get any hints in the right direction that would be a great help! and also sorry for weird formatting if any first time poster.

Comment: `return lx` is indented too far such that you loop ends after 1 value is added to `lx`. It should be indented at the same line as your while statement.

Comment: As an aside, what you're calling a "def function" is typically just called a "function". Other kinds of functions, like lambdas, are comparatively unusual enough that they're the ones that get referred to by a different name.

Comment: Thank you for the answer Ben and I will keep that in mind Charles

Comment: Strictly speaking, a lambda *expression* is just another way of defining the same kind of thing a `def` statement defines. Fundamentally, there's no difference, although the lambda expression leaves behind a "fingerprint", for example the value of the function's `__name__` attribute.

Answer (score 1):

You were really close. The way the return statement works with functions is that once the return statement is hit the function ends. Since the return statement is right after the append line it would add one number and then exit the function. You needed to shift the return statment to the same line as the for loop to ensure the for loop gets executed, but nice job getting that far.

```
import random

def fill(nx, x, y):
    lx = []
    for j in range(nx):
        randNum = random.randint(x, y)
        if randNum not in lx:
            lx.append(randNum)
    return lx


n = 25
a = 10
b = 50

myList = fill(n, a, b)
print(myList)
```

Output:

```
[11, 29, 16, 33, 20, 22, 48, 47, 25, 28, 38, 30, 36, 40]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `random.sample`:

```
import random
def fill(nx, x, y):
    return random.sample(range(x, y + 1), nx)
```

Sample output of `fill(25, 10, 50)`:

```
[25, 45, 35, 42, 24, 41, 43, 14, 36, 13, 46, 32, 29, 28, 22, 47, 39, 10, 30, 21, 33, 31, 17, 44, 34]
```